# What’s the offset distance for a Mars Fly-by?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, astronomy, space-travel

Would anyone know where to look or know how to calculate the offset distance at which fly-by on Mars may be performed. It’s the variable ‘x’ in the formula 8.3-20. (Bate Mueller Astrodynamics Principles)

[image]

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, calculate x? X as function of what orbital parameters? Depending on what is given in your particular problem this is arbitrarily easy or complicated...

Comment: I am calculating the patched conic approximation for interplanetary travel. So in this case x represents the offset distance for flyby past Mars (from Earth, but it shouldn’t matter).